# How do you access a list element without assigning a class/id to it?

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I'm trying to change the color of a link in a `<li>` element without assigning an id to it on a certain page of my website.
So far I've had no luck. I've tried the following:

```
function writeNav() {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css"> <ul id="nav">  <li>  <a href="/">Home</a>  </li>  <li>    <a href="#">Interests</a>  </li>  <li>  <a href="#">Gaming</a>  <li>  <a href="/Resume.pdf">Resume</a>  </li>  </ul>');

    if (window.location.href == "mywebsite.com/anime.html") {
        document.getElementByTagName("li")[0].style.color="#FFE4E1";
    }
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById("nav").a.style.color = "#FFE4E1";
```

I've done quite a bit of looking around but with not luck.

Comment: Use `.getElement**s**ByTagName(...)` instead (note the s)

Comment: @RandyCasburn hmm that doesn't seem to have done the trick.

Comment: `document.querySelector("#nav>li>a")`

Comment: I just tested it. Your code works fine with `getElementsByTagName`. I had to comment out the `if()` statement and the css file `href`, but it works fine. You don't expect to change the link colors do you?  Look at the bullet - it will show the new color. The link colors are set by CSS psuedo classes you must override.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol 's answer is the closest I get. Only the first `<li>` changes color. I'll keep digging around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so going off of @Niet's answer I was able to achieve this using

```
document.querySelectorAll("#nav>li>a");
```

The full solution for anyone wondering is as follows:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#nav>li a");
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    list[i].style.color = "black";
}
```

Comment: Good job solving it, and thanks for posting an answer for others to see. I edited your answer to include `var` before your loop variable, as otherwise you may be modifying a global variable.

Comment: Futhermore, you may want to consider using modern language features: `const` and `for..of` loops, in this case, like so: `for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll("#nav>li a")) elem.style.color = "black";`

Comment: @YonaAppletree I will definitely look into it. I'm still new to JS as a hobbyist :) upvote maybe? :P

Comment: Totally. And really, for this type of thing, you probably just want to use CSS. Make a class on your #nav, for example, that sets the color of the links to black. `#nav.darkLinks > li > a { color: black; }` for example

Comment: And welcome to hobby! I've been at it for >20 years and still find joy in this quirky language.